# Is it possible to read and write Content Type Properties in VBA Word 2016 on MacOS?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, sharepoint-online

I am using a Word dotm file as a template for a SharePoint content type. This word-template contains a Form, opened by a statement in the `Document_New()` event. A combobox on that form contains the value of a content type property. VBA is used to set the combobox text value via `Document.ContentTypeProperties`:

```
Me.cmbComboBox.Text = ThisDocument.ContentTypeProperties("NameOfContentTypeProperty")
```

This works in Word 2016 on Windows. But in Word 2016 on MacOS this call results in the following error:

> Run-time error 5948 This command is not available on this platform.

It seems that this property of the Document object is not available on MacOS.

Does anyone know how to read and write these content type properties in VBA Word 2016 on MacOS?

Comment: See John Korchok's site for much more on using OOXML on the Mac. Here is the page on Content Controls. http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/  --- Another potential method is to create your form in the Windows OS. Features tied to XML often work on a Mac even if you can't create them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to read and write the content type properties by editing the XML of the document using the following functions. This works on both Mac and PC.

```
Function getContentTypeProperty(strElementName As String, docDocument As Word.Document) As String

    Dim xmlNode As CustomXMLNode
    Dim xmlPart As CustomXMLPart

    Set xmlPart = docDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties").Item(1)

    Set xmlNode = xmlPart.SelectSingleNode("/ns0:properties/documentManagement/ns3:" & strElementName)

    If xmlNode Is Nothing Then
        getContentTypeProperty = ""
    Else
        getContentTypeProperty = xmlNode.Text
    End If

End Function

Function setContentTypeProperty(strElementName As String, docDocument As Word.Document, strValue As String) As Boolean

    Dim xmlNode As CustomXMLNode
    Dim xmlPart As CustomXMLPart

    Set xmlPart = docDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties").Item(1)

    Set xmlNode = xmlPart.SelectSingleNode("/ns0:properties/documentManagement/ns3:" & strElementName)

    If xmlNode Is Nothing Then
        setContentTypeProperty = False
    Else
        If getAttributeValueByName(xmlNode.Attributes, "nil") = "true" Then setAttributeValueByName xmlNode.Attributes, "nil", "false"
        xmlNode.Text = strValue
        setContentTypeProperty = True
    End If

End Function

Function getAttributeValueByName(xmlAttributes As CustomXMLNodes, strAttributeName As String) As String

    Dim xmlAttribute As CustomXMLNode
    Dim strValue As String

    For Each xmlAttribute In xmlAttributes  
        If xmlAttribute.BaseName = strAttributeName Then strValue = xmlAttribute.NodeValue
    Next

    getAttributeValueByName = strValue

End Function
```

Comment: If this is the answer to your question please mark it with the green checkmark. That shows that the question is answered and it gives you points!

Answer (score 0):

If the command doesn't exist for Mac you might have to use AppleScript. Unfortunately, I can't help you with AppleScript and I can't find any documentation from MS about what is or isn't available on a Mac.

Here is a compiler directive that will allow you to run different code on Mac or PC.

```
'Test the conditional compiler constant #Mac
#If Mac Then
'I am a Mac
    Me.cmbComboBox.Text = AppleScriptTask ("MyAppleScriptFile.applescript", "myapplescripthandler", "my parameter string") 
#Else
'I am Windows
    Me.cmbComboBox.Text = ThisDocument.ContentTypeProperties("NameOfContentTypeProperty")
#End If
```

Comment: I could not find "content type property" in the Microsoft Word dictionary. When it's not available than reading and writing the content type properties by using AppleScript is not possible.